# Remove all meetings created by a user linked to a Office 365 Room mailbox

Tags: powershell, office365

A client of ours has two rooms in Office 365 under "Resources > Rooms & Equipment", one of which is a meeting room that users can book and invite people to. When a user is invited and accepts it creates a calendar event. However, recently one user left and deleted his calendar events which subsequently, has been removed for everyone else. However, other users cannot book this meeting room as it says it is already booked under his name. The email account that booked the meetings is still active and will be until the end of the month.

Is there a way of deleting all bookings linked to a specific user, or possibly a way of getting a list of all upcoming and previous bookings? I have access to Office 365 and Powershell, any help would be great.

Have tried to find calendar for the room and can do this but unsure of how to get list of calender events.

Comment: You can use `Get/Remove-MgUserEvent` in powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.calendar/remove-mguserevent?view=graph-powershell-1.0 but for a one-off it's probably easier to just load up the meeting room's calendar in outlook (list view), search for the user by name, and delete the events all at once

Comment: Thanks for this, in the end I gave the user that had left delegation permissions on the rooms mailbox and calendar and then was able to see who booked which meets and where and manually cancelled them